# Fixed position header - transition effect on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just made some scrolling sticky menu on my school project website, and i found this little problem. It's about transition hover effect of my menu links. You can see default menu is absolute positioned and at this stage transition is working perfectly, but when you scroll page down it header becomes fixed and transition effects stops working

here's my page: http://79.170.44.87/tatras.eu/

//edit: it's just problem of google chrome

//edit2: + its somehow cause of video background but i dont know why

Comment: ok FIX: video background had -1 z-index. I think it was problem with negative z-index. I changed it to 0 and its working perfecty.